# Lexicographical order in firebase (accents and capital letters)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to write a search view controller for an iphone app. I use firebase for my backend and want to search for names.

Names can be strange and have accents and capital letters, how will firebase lexicographical order when I limit my query to the first 100 values starting with "John".

Will the query results include such results as "Jôhn", "john" and "jôhn". 
Do the lexicographical ordering algorithm  assign the same value to "j" and "J" and to "o" and "ô"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experimentantion I concluded that the fireabase lexicographical ordering algorithm DOES NOT  assign the same value to "j" and "J" and to "o" and "ô".

Have that in mind when building search functions for your apps.